# Facebook not login with install facebook app in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, facebook-login

I had installed a Facebook login in my flutter app . and everything alright. but when install Facebook app.  login square show and when press login nothing does and not log in. why?

Answer (score 1):

You should use

facebookLogin.loginBehavior = FacebookLoginBehavior.webOnly;

so it will always open facebook login page in webview

Comment: is any solution for user which have installed facebook apps to get data in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit AppDelegate.swift**

---

```
import FBSDKCoreKit
..........

    override func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL,
                                options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
        if url.scheme == "fbXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" {
            return ApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application,open:url,options:options)
         }
       
         .......
      }
```